# Is it possible to arrange minipages in this specific way?

Tags: minipage

I am trying to arrange two tables and a formula using minipages, to get something like this:

[image: What I want]

So far, the closest I got was, with the code below:

[image: What i got]

```
  \documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}
  \usepackage{float}



  \begin{document}

  \begin{table}[H]
      \begin{minipage}[b]{0.40\linewidth}
            \caption{Short table}
            \qquad
            \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
              A & B & C & D \\ \hline
              7 & 4 & 7 & 1 \\
              4 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
              5 & 5 & 9 & 2 \\
           \end{tabular}
     \end{minipage}
     \qquad \quad
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.55\linewidth}
            \caption{This table continues to the right}
            \begin{tabular}{c c c c}
                  E  & F & G & H    \\ \hline
                  3  & 1 & 1 & 1   \\
                  6  & 4 & 4 & 1   \\
                  9  & 8 & 7 & 9   \\
                  12 & 2 & 1 & 8   \\
                  15 & 8 & 1 & 7   \\
                  18 & 8 & 1 & 4   \\
                  21 & 9 & 1 & 5   \\
                  24 & 5 & 2 & 4 
              \end{tabular}
          \end{minipage}
     \begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\linewidth}
         \[R_{LED}=\frac{1.31+1.39+1.32}{3}=1.34k\Omega\]
    \end{minipage}
   \end{table}

   \end{document}
```

I appreciate any help you can give

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make *two* minipages:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.45\linewidth}
\caption{Short table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
A & B & C & D \\ \hline
7 & 4 & 7 & 1 \\
4 & 3 & 4 & 9 \\
5 & 5 & 9 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\bigskip\bigskip

$\displaystyle R_{LED}=\frac{1.31+1.39+1.32}{3}=1.34k\Omega$
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.55\linewidth}
\caption{This table continues to the right}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c c c}
E& F & G & H\\ \hline
3& 1 & 1 & 1 \\
6& 4 & 4 & 1 \\
9& 8 & 7 & 9 \\
12 & 2 & 1 & 8 \\
15 & 8 & 1 & 7 \\
18 & 8 & 1 & 4 \\
21 & 9 & 1 & 5 \\
24 & 5 & 2 & 4 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Don't use `[H]`: your documents will look bad. You've been warned. `;-)`

Comment: Ow. You're using two `\caption{}` inside the same `table`. This will work also with two `\labels{}`?

Comment: @Sigur Yes, of course, provided `\label` is next to the `\caption` it refers to (inside the minipage, in this case).

Comment: Alright, tried that and changed minipage[b] to minipage[t], as you did, otherwise the tables would me misaligned. Now it's perfect, thank you very much.